# Meaning of FailureListener on getting last location in Google API

Tags: java, android

I'm using Google API to getting the last location in my android app.
Can you please explain me, why or what can be the reason that my app is reaching `addOnFailureListener`?

I have my code like this:

```
 mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            if (location != null) {

                                //Sucesso na localização
                                double altitude = location.getAltitude();
                                locAtual.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                                locAtual.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            //Erro

                        }
                    });
        }
```

I just want to know what are the reasons, for the fail of listener.

Comment: Did you add location permissions? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that device have no LastLocation for your apps. You can use requestLocationUpdates() if getLastLocation() called OnFailureListener() callback. Hopely it can help you